How to correctly embed JavaSciptCore into Linux application?
I'm trying to embed JavaScriptCore library for JS execution into Linux
application and I have a problem. The library emits signal SIGUSR1
during the script execution. Shouldn't it be handled by the library
itself? If I handle and skip the signal, then the application stucks.
If I don't handle this signal, then the application crashes.
So how can I correctly embed the library and how should I work with
that signals?

JavaScriptCore is designed to use SIGUSR1 to suspend and resume threads internally for garbage collection. It should have handler for it.
If you have set your own handler then you should use JSC_SIGNAL_FOR_GC to set different signal for JavaScriptCore.

It seems I'e found where this handler is setup: https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit/blob/da808677339de833db3e1d36ca34dda8464b4638/Source/WTF/wtf/posix/ThreadingPOSIX.cpp#L181
So probably I should call WTF::initialize() first of all?

Perhaps you should start from getting some examples to run. Like there https://karhm.com/javascriptcore_c_api/ If you can not run those then the issue is in how you built it, if you can then the issue is in how you try to use it.
